# Filter namespaces and replace their prefixes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

How do i keep only the required namespaces URIs (maybe unused) and replace all their prefixes (based on list of prefixes and URIs) with `XSLT` (1.0)? The original combinations of prefixes and namespaces URIs may change!

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:node_0 
xmlns:ns6="http://a.com" 
xmlns:ns5="http://b.com" 
xmlns:ns8="http://c.com" 
xmlns:ns7="http://d.com" 
xmlns:ns2="http://e.com"
xmlns:ns4="http://f.com"
xmlns:ns3="http://g.com">
    <node_1 attr_1="attr_1_val" attr_2="attr_2_val">
        <ns4:node_11>node_11_val</ns4:node_11>
        <ns4:node_12 attr_1="attr_1_val" attr_2="attr_2_val">
            <ns2:node_121>node_121_val</ns2:node_121>
            <ns4:node_122>
                <node_1221>node_1221_val</node_1221>
                <ns3:node_1222>
                    <node_12221 attr_1="attr_1_val">
                        <node_122211>node_122211_val</node_122211>
                    </node_12221>
                </ns3:node_1222>
            </ns4:node_122>
            <node_123>
                <node_1231 attr_1="attr_1_val">
                    <node_12311>node_12311_val</node_12311>
                </node_1231>            
            </node_123>
        </ns4:node_12>
        <ns3:node_13>
            <node_131>
                <ns3:node_1311>node_1311_val</ns3:node_1311>
                <node_1312 attr_1="attr_1_val" attr_2="attr_2_val" attr_3="attr_3_val" attr_4="attr_4_val">
                    <ns3:node_13121/>
                </node_1312>
            </node_131>
        </ns3:node_13>
        <node_14/>
    </node_1>
    <ns4:node_2 attr_1="attr_1_val" attr_2="attr_2_val" attr_3="attr_3_val">
        <ns4:node_21>node_21_val</ns4:node_21>
    </ns4:node_2>
</ns4:node_0>
```

Required namespaces URIs and their prefixes:

```
b_ns="http://b.com" 
e_ns="http://e.com"
f_ns="http://f.com"
g_ns="http://g.com"
```

So the required output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<f_ns:node_0 
xmlns:b_ns="http://b.com" 
xmlns:e_ns="http://e.com"
xmlns:f_ns="http://f.com"
xmlns:g_ns="http://g.com">
    <node_1 attr_1="attr_1_val" attr_2="attr_2_val">
        <f_ns:node_11>node_11_val</f_ns:node_11>
        <f_ns:node_12 attr_1="attr_1_val" attr_2="attr_2_val">
            <e_ns:node_121>node_121_val</e_ns:node_121>
            <f_ns:node_122>
                <node_1221>node_1221_val</node_1221>
                <g_ns:node_1222>
                    <node_12221 attr_1="attr_1_val">
                        <node_122211>node_122211_val</node_122211>
                    </node_12221>
                </g_ns:node_1222>
            </f_ns:node_122>
            <node_123>
                <node_1231 attr_1="attr_1_val">
                    <node_12311>node_12311_val</node_12311>
                </node_1231>            
            </node_123>
        </f_ns:node_12>
        <g_ns:node_13>
            <node_131>
                <g_ns:node_1311>node_1311_val</g_ns:node_1311>
                <node_1312 attr_1="attr_1_val" attr_2="attr_2_val" attr_3="attr_3_val" attr_4="attr_4_val">
                    <g_ns:node_13121/>
                </node_1312>
            </node_131>
        </g_ns:node_13>
        <node_14/>
    </node_1>
    <f_ns:node_2 attr_1="attr_1_val" attr_2="attr_2_val" attr_3="attr_3_val">
        <f_ns:node_21>node_21_val</f_ns:node_21>
    </f_ns:node_2>
</f_ns:node_0>
```

There is a `XSLT` code only for filtering namespaces URIs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">            
           <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
            <xsl:template match="*">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[
                     .='http://b.com'
                     or .='http://e.com'
                     or .='http://f.com'
                     or .='http://g.com"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's very difficult to write complete code, as there is very little experience with `XSLT`.
Thanx in advance!

Comment: Do you know in advance the name and/or the namespace of the root element?

Comment: @michael.hor257k if necessary, only the name of the root element is known.

Comment: Only the local name, or the namespace too (by namespace I mean the URI - `http://f.com` in the given example)?

Comment: The local name of the root element and its namespace URI are known, but the prefix of its URI may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate tasks here:

1. Replace the prefixes of namespaces **used** by elements of the given XML;
2. Add the declarations of the **unused** namespaces to the root element.

The first task is quite simple, since the prefixes are by definition not significant. All you need to do is declare the namespaces using the prefixes you want, then rename the elements in the corresponding namespace using the new prefix.

The second task can be simple if - as you said in the comment - you know the namespace URI of the root element. Then you can copy the namespace declarations from the stylesheet to the elements in that namespace (and hope that the processor is smart enough to do so only once):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:b_ns="http://b.com" 
xmlns:e_ns="http://e.com"
xmlns:f_ns="http://f.com"
xmlns:g_ns="http://g.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="b_ns:*">
    <xsl:element name="b_ns:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e_ns:*">
    <xsl:element name="e_ns:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- this matches the root element -->
<xsl:template match="f_ns:*">
    <xsl:element name="f_ns:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/namespace::*[not(name()='xsl')]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="g_ns:*">
    <xsl:element name="g_ns:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note:**

None of this should be necessary. As noted above, namespace prefixes have no significance. And unused namespaces declarations are redundant. Apparently, this "problem" is caused by a non-conforming parser at the receiving end - and it would be much more productive to fix that.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do I understand correctly: to solve the 2nd problem, you use only first 'copy-of' in template which matches to root element (without that string only used namespaces will be left)? Your note is certainly correct, but it is not under my control.

Comment: Without the instruction to copy the namespaces only used namespaces will be declared - and not necessarily at the root element.

Comment: I'll test a little more and decide on the result: everything is not clear yet. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: 1. String starts with "<xsl:copy-of select="document..." doesn't work (Add/remove it doesn't change anything). 2. Transformer gives an error when converting: "Namespace for prefix 'f_ns' has not been declared." Deleting template with this prefix results in the same error only with a different prefix.

Comment: @slider I test my answers before I post them. Which processor/environment are you using that returns these errors?

Comment: First, I checked in https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html: parsing passed, but the specified string was useless. Then checked in the target environment (Java (JDK1. 8. 0_221), javax. xml. transform.Transformer): Parsing failed. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: You cannot use an online tester for this, because of the `document()` function. As for JDK, I don't know. This is 100% pure XSLT 1.0 and any conforming processor should be able to execute it (though the exact result may vary).

Comment: The solution for the JDK is to add to each template with prefixes, in the tag '<xsl:element>', the attribute: namespace="{namespace-uri()}". Now everything is fine, only after the conversion the xml attribute: standalone="yes" is removed.

Comment: You should be able to add it via the `xsl:output` instruction.